# Cefsharp - Вызов метода для управления формой из кода страницы

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Начал потихоньку изучать Cefsharp.

Возникла первая проблема с которой пока не могу справится. 
Использовал данный пример: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/173/how-to-use-cefsharp-chromium-embedded-framework-csharp-in-a-winforms-application

Со страницы линкой пытаюсь вызвать метод формы hideApp(), но ничего не происходит (При том, что closeApp() прекрасно работает).

Класс:

```
class CefCustomObject
{
    private static ChromiumWebBrowser _instanceBrowser = null;
    private static Form1 _instanceMainForm = null;

    public CefCustomObject(ChromiumWebBrowser originalBrowser, Form1 mainForm)
    {
        _instanceBrowser = originalBrowser;
        _instanceMainForm = mainForm;
    }

    public void showDevTools()
    {
        _instanceBrowser.ShowDevTools();
    }

    public void hideApp()
    {
        Form1 fullScreenForm = new Form1();
        fullScreenForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized; //не работает

        _instanceMainForm .WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized; //тоже не работает
    }

    public void closeApp()
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    public void opencmd()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c pause");
        Process.Start(start);
    }
}
```

Как вызываю:

```
<div class="btns" onclick="cefCustomObject.hideApp();">
```

Comment: ошибка говорит что ты пытаешся инициализировать CEF несколько раз. Поставь брейкпоинт на начале программы и пройдись построчно по коду. И это не имеет отношения к сворачиванию в трей.

Comment: @andrew, сама программа работает. Но при попытке нажать на ту самую кнопку, вылетает ошибка. Где я пытаюсь инициализировать CEF несколько раз? Он один раз инициализируется в Form1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Нужно было попытаться использовать Form1 в собственном потоке.

```
public void hideApp()
{
    _instanceMainForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
    {
        _instanceMainForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }));
}
```

Comment: это НЕ сворачивание в трей. --__--"